# Trying to highlight current menu item in Drupal 8 using hook_preprocess_menu

Tags: php, drupal-8

I have the below function to create active trail functionality. So if I were to have /blog as a "parent" and a post of /blog/mypost, when on mypost the blog link would show as highlighted. I don't want to have to make menu items for all the blog posts. The problem is when caching is turned on (not using settings.local.php and debug turned off) the getRequestUri isn't changing on some pages. It seems to be cached depending on the page. It works fine with page caching turned off but I'd like to get this working with caching. Is there a better way to check for the current path and apply the active class?

```
function mytheme_preprocess_menu(&$variables, $hook) {
  if($variables['theme_hook_original'] == 'menu__main'){
    $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
    if($node){
      $current_path = \Drupal::request()->getRequestUri();
      $items = $variables['items'];
      foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
        // If current path starts with a part of another path i.e. a parent, set active to li.
        if (0 === strpos($current_path, $item['url']->toString())) {
          // Add active link.
          $variables['items'][$key]['attributes']['class'] .= ' menu-item--active-trail';
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've also tried putting this into a module to try and see if I can get the current path to then do the twig logic in the menu--main.twig.html template but I have the same problem.

```
function highlight_menu_sections_template_preprocess_default_variables_alter(&$variables) {
  $variables['current_path'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}
```

Comment: I suspect the theme layer is not the ideal place for this logic and that's why you're running into caching issues. I think you need to be manipulating the active trail much earlier. Sorry I don't know offhand how to do that in D8.

Comment: Looking for something similar, just found https://www.drupal.org/node/2240003 -- "There is no way to set the active link - override the service if you need more control."

Comment: https://www.dunix-data.de/blog/drupal_8_set_menu_active_trail_based_on_type_of_currently_viewed_node This might help

Answer (score 2):

After a very long time trying all sorts of things, I found an excellent module which addresses exactly this problem. Install and go, not configuration, it just works:

https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_trail_by_path

Stable versions for D7 and D8.

Answer (score 0):

I tried declaring an active path as part of a custom menu block, and even then my declared trail gets cached. Assuming it's related to the "There is no way to set the active link - override the service if you need more control." statement in [this changelog](https://www.drupal.org/node/2240003), though why [MenuTreeParameters->setActiveTrail()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Menu!MenuTreeParameters.php/function/MenuTreeParameters%3A%3AsetActiveTrail/8) exists is anybody's guess.

For the curious (and for me when I search for this later!), here's my block's build() function:

```
public function build() {
  $menu_tree = \Drupal::menuTree();
  $parameters = new MenuTreeParameters();
  $parameters->setRoot('menu_link_content:700c69e6-785b-4db7-be49-73188b47b5a3')->setMinDepth(1)->setMaxDepth(1)->onlyEnabledLinks();

  // An array of routes and menu_link_content ids to set as active
  $define_active_mlid = array(
    'view.press_releases.page_1' => 385
  );
  $route_name = \Drupal::request()->get(RouteObjectInterface::ROUTE_NAME);
  if (array_key_exists($route_name, $define_active_mlid)) {
    $menu_link = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('menu_link_content')->loadByProperties(array('id' => $define_active_mlid[$route_name]));
    $link = array_shift($menu_link);
    $parameters->setActiveTrail(array('menu_link_content:' . $link->uuid()));
  }

  $footer_tree = $menu_tree->load('footer', $parameters);
  $manipulators = array(
    array('callable' => 'menu.default_tree_manipulators:checkAccess'),
    array('callable' => 'menu.default_tree_manipulators:generateIndexAndSort'),
  );
  $tree = $menu_tree->transform($footer_tree, $manipulators);
  $menu = $menu_tree->build($tree);

  return array(
    'menu' => $menu,
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[adding a new answer since this is a completely different approach than my earlier one]

If a CSS-based solution is acceptable, this seems to work okay:

```
.page-node-type-press-release {
  a[data-drupal-link-system-path="press-room/press-releases"] {
    // active CSS styles here
  }
}
```